# Can I use a value from earlier in a class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

Can this appear in a class declaration, or do I risk problems by not using a `#define` constant for `sNumInts`?

```
    static const int sNumInts = 15;
    std::array<int,sNumInts> myInts;
```

Comment: @Lou: Of course, so I know it works for my compiler on my architecture during a waning crescent.

Comment: Since you mention `std::array`, in C++11 you can also use a `constexpr` instead of the `static`.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly legal. `sNumInts` is an Integral Constant Expression (ICE) which can be manipulated and created at compile-time with machinery- including template metaprogramming. Bu the simple creation of one is as you have defined it.

Comment: Yes. And you don't need the `static`.